# Stuck in a loop when trying to log in

Tags: symfony, azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement a SAML2 SSO setup with Azure AD as the IDP and SP using the hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle on Symfony3.

When I access the login path on my app, the browser is stuck in a circular loop between Azure AD and my APP which I've not been able to decipher.

Here are my configurations:

*config.yml*

```
hslavich_onelogin_saml:
# Basic settings
idp:
    entityId: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/azure_app_id/saml2'
    singleSignOnService:
        url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/azure_app_id/saml2'
        binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect'
    singleLogoutService:
        url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/azure_app_id/saml2'
        binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect'
    x509cert: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/AzureCert.cer'
sp:
    entityId: 'https://myapp.com/saml/meta'
    assertionConsumerService:
        url: 'https://myapp.com/saml/acs'
        binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST'
    singleLogoutService:
        url: 'https://myapp.com/saml/logout'
        binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect'
```

*Azure AD configuration*

```
Identifier(EntityId): https://myapp.com/saml/meta
Reply URL (ACS): https://myapp.com/saml/acs
```

Would anyone be able to see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sign out URL and try - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/wsfederation?wa=wsignout1.0

Comment: I already got it to work but this is the correct answer thanks

Comment: @MasindeMuliro What solution did you use for this problem, I am also facing the same issue in my application